# How do I write an Applescript for iTunes to find iPhone apps?

Tags: applescript, itunes, itunes-store, itunes-app

How can I write with AppleScript an action to search for any iPhone app (for example Facebook) in iTunes and download it to my computer?

Comment: What have you tried till now? Show the attempts you have done, and please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything in the dictionary in place for this, so you'll probably have to use UI Scripting (http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/)